# Is this outputting correct RSS XML?

Tags: php, xml, rss

See this page,

Why doesnt it show like it does when you enter a .xml file?

Or should it not do. When i look in ctrl+u for source, it looks correct.

I have this in my php file at the top:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><rss version=\"2.0\">";
?>
```

I want `<title>` to be a element, not a html tag, which the browser thinks it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has several errors. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftilbudibyen.com%2Frss%2F).

The basic problem is that this doesn't appear to have much resemblance to [RSS](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) at all (lacking, for instance, any `<item>`s).

For whatever reason, `header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");` is not being respected either. The server is claiming that it is an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<?php echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"; ?>` from your view. I was getting following error :-

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start
>   of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first
>   error.

I was using Codeigniter. simply remove `echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'` from your. Surely it will work.